# If it’s possible, how do you use the Shoelace components in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, shoelace

am a Font Awesome user and have seen the notice about the acquisition by/of Shoelace.  Wanted to get a start and wondered if shoelace can be used with Wordpress.  If you can how do you do it?

Sorry if this has been asked before.

Paul

Comment: You should just be able to enqueue the stylesheets and scripts and then use the library to integrate it with your theme.  Whether you make the files local or from the CDN is up to you.  Then it's a matter of implementing it the way you would on any project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tony.  Enqueuing etc is currently just out of my comfort zone but after 30years in commercial IT I’ve had to do this loads of times before I’m just a little slower